# How to backup files to another server and then delete from source server

Tags: php, cron, scp

How to copy by CRON every day files from source server to destination server (create backup) and then delete these files from source server?
I need copy just newest files (but it's not important if copied files will be deleted)

I've found these solutions

https://serverfault.com/questions/259938/cron-job-to-copy-file-from-one-location-to-another-for-new-files-daily

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166542/transferring-data-between-servers

But I don't know how to be sure all the files are transfered correctly and I can delete it from source server.

There are 2 options how to do that - by shh or some combination with PHP.

Can you show me a correct way? Accurate solution would be best because I'm not sure with these things (SSH, scp, etc.).

Comment: Maybe rsync should do the trick... But I'm not sure with --delete flag

Answer (score 0):

My working solution:

```
50 3 * * * sudo rsync --remove-source-files /SOURCE_PATH/* SSH_LOGIN:/DESTINATION_PATH
```